# How to transfer JSON block from one HTTP query to another in jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter

The problem itself is in:
I have a response from one HTTP sampler, which looks like

```
{
"data": [
    {"report_date": "xx.xx.xxxx"},
    {"report_date": "xx.xx.xxxx"},
    {"report_date": "xx.xx.xxxx"}
],
"pagination": {
    "totalRow": 58,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 0
},
"accessButtons": null
```

}

I need to transfer the whole block with report dates to another HTTP sampler.
How exactly can I do this? I've managed how to grab one report date and how to make a variable for every report date found, but I need to either put all of them as a block to the next sampler or, somehow, to make this block from the list of variables. From where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data
   def payload = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(data).toPrettyString()
   log.info('------Generated JSON--------')
   log.info(payload)
   vars.put('data', payload)
   ```
3. That's it, the contents of `data` element are not stored into `${data}` JMeter Variable:

   [image]

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the all response using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to a variable using regex

```
[^`]*
```

I use not (`^`) ` values to get all response with newlines

If it's inner JSON, you can put the text before and after in regex

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is best if you use JSON extractor in jmeter, and use `$..data[:3]` JSON Path that will fetch the "data" block and bring back lines in index 0, 1, and 2. Take a look at this article and try:

[How to Parse a JSON Response Using JMeter’s JSON Extractor](https://www.testingexcellence.com/parse-json-response-using-jmeters-json-extractor/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a Post Processor -> JSON Extracter to the request.
   [image]
2. Give a variable name "MyVariable" and in the field "JSON path Expression" just give "$"

[image]

3. Supply the variable "MyVariable" into the next request as required.